# What is AlertRecipients system process?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, processes, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

On specified Android 2.3.6 device, there is a system process called:

> AlertRecipients

What does it mean/do?

Comment: Since your handset is a Dual SIM I am guessing this is related to the functionality of that handset specifically...

Comment: It's for sure some Samsung process (` com.samsung.AlertRecipients`). But there're also "Alarm Recipients" mentioned in the [ANDROID USERS GUIDE - Omega CarLink](http://www.omegacarlink.com/manuals/OMEGACARLINK%20Android%20users%20guide.pdf): *Provided your CarLink system is installed and connected with a compatible Omega system you will have the ability to send alert notices from the vehicle if the alarm system is trigger by an open door or the shock sensor.*

Comment: Just found an additional hint at the [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1160976): *`AlertRecipients.apk` For setting up an alert SMS* (the thread is about the SGS2).